# Why do people seem to do the opposite of what they were told regardless if their actions have repercussions or not?

Tags: social-psychology, decision-making, behavior

In My Country Uganda, we are put under total lockdown. a curfew was imposed that starts at 7 Pm, but on the contrary, when it clocked 7 PM, people were not in their houses but rather on the verandas and balconies and some on streets to see how the security was going to enforce the curfew.

Experiments reveal, for example, that people are more likely to watch violent TV shows and play violent video games when labels warn against them. And there are many examples of books becoming more popular after they’re banned.

When someone tells you not to think about something, your mind has a sneaky way of returning to that very thought. In a [brilliant study led by psychologist Daniel Wegner](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0898622239) (Wegner, 1989), people were told not to think about a white bear. They spent the next 5 minutes thinking aloud, saying everything that came to mind was thinking of a white bear.

**My Question**
Why do people seem to do the opposite of what they were told regardless if their actions have repercussions?
This applies to directions given by Parents, Bosses, Drill Sergeants, Police (under certain circumstances), Firemen and Teachers/Professors.

Credit: Bussiness Insider

### References

Wegner, D. M. (1989). *White bears and other unwanted thoughts: Suppression, obsession, and the psychology of mental control*. New York: Penguin Press.